# How to count lost customers in a dynamic time period, using date hierarchy--Power BI, DAX

Tags: powerbi

I'd like to create measures for new, active, and lost customers, such that the measures are calculated appropriately for whatever granularity of time period is in use in the report.

e.g. if a graphic is displaying monthly data,

- "active customers" are those who placed an order in a given month,
- "new customers" are those who placed an order in a given month, but NOT in any preceding month;
- "lost customers" are those who placed an order in any preceding month, but not in a given month,

if instead the graphic is displaying weekly or quarterly data, the measures would adjust the periods accordingly.

With the following set of measures, which refer to a Calendar table and a SalesInvoiceLines table,
I get the intended result for Active and New customers--it works when displayed yearly, quarterly, monthly, etc.

The _LostCustomers count below does not produce the intended result--it instead generates a cumulative count of lost customers over time

```
_ActiveCustomers = 
VAR Customers = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(SalesInvoiceLines[OrderCustomerHashKey]))
RETURN COUNTROWS(Customers)

_NewCustomers = 
VAR Customers = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(SalesInvoiceLines[OrderCustomerHashKey]))
VAR PriorCustomers = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(SalesInvoiceLines[OrderCustomerHashKey]), 
                                    FILTER(ALL('Calendar'),
                                           'Calendar'[Date] < min('Calendar'[Date])))
RETURN COUNTROWS(EXCEPT(Customers, PriorCustomers))

_LostCustomers = 
VAR PresentCustomers = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(SalesInvoiceLines[OrderCustomerHashKey]), 
                                    FILTER(ALL('Calendar'),
                                           'Calendar'[Date] > min('Calendar'[Date])))
VAR PriorCustomers = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES(SalesInvoiceLines[OrderCustomerHashKey]), 
                                    FILTER(ALL('Calendar'),
                                           'Calendar'[Date] < min('Calendar'[Date])))
RETURN COUNTROWS(EXCEPT(PriorCustomers, PresentCustomers))
```

[image]

Note how _LostCustomers strictly increases each period. This _LostCustomers metric counts a customer as lost for **every period** after the one in which they placed their last order.

How can we exclude customers previously-reported as lost from the lost customer count, so that a customer is recorded as lost in **only the first period** in which they placed no orders?

[This approach](https://blog.enterprisedna.co/analyze-who-your-lost-customers-are-using-power-bi-dax/) solves this problem by hard-coding a 60-day threshold. Can we solve the problem without pre-defining the period of analysis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will work with a minimum calendar granularity of MONTH:

```
_LostCustomers = 
  var monthSpan = DATEDIFF(MIN('Calendar'[Date]), MAX('Calendar'[Date]) + 1, MONTH)

  var prevPeriodCustomers = CALCULATETABLE(
    VALUES(SalesInvoiceLines[OrderCustomerHashKey]), 
    PARALLELPERIOD('Calendar'[Date], - monthSpan, MONTH) 
  )

  var presentCustomers = CALCULATETABLE(
    VALUES(SalesInvoiceLines[OrderCustomerHashKey]),
    FILTER(ALL('Calendar'), 'Calendar'[Date] >= min('Calendar'[Date]))
  )

  RETURN COUNTROWS(EXCEPT(prevPeriodCustomers, PresentCustomers))
```

And the following for a minimum calendar granularity of DAY (if you need it):

```
_LostCustomers = 
  var monthSpan = DATEDIFF(MIN('Calendar'[Date]), MAX('Calendar'[Date]) + 1, MONTH)
  var daySpan = DATEDIFF(MIN('Calendar'[Date]), MAX('Calendar'[Date]) + 1, DAY)

  var prevPeriodCustomersM = CALCULATETABLE(
    VALUES(SalesInvoiceLines[OrderCustomerHashKey]), 
    PARALLELPERIOD('Calendar'[Date], - monthSpan, MONTH) 
  )

  var prevPeriodCustomersD = CALCULATETABLE(
    VALUES(SalesInvoiceLines[OrderCustomerHashKey]), 
    DATESINPERIOD('Calendar'[Date], MIN('Calendar'[Date]) - daySpan, daySpan, DAY)
  )

  var presentCustomers = CALCULATETABLE(
    VALUES(SalesInvoiceLines[OrderCustomerHashKey]),
    FILTER(ALL('Calendar'), 'Calendar'[Date] >= min('Calendar'[Date]))
  )

  RETURN IF(monthSpan = 0,
    COUNTROWS(EXCEPT(prevPeriodCustomersD, PresentCustomers)),
    COUNTROWS(EXCEPT(prevPeriodCustomersM, PresentCustomers))
  )
```

Comment: This is great! It also helped my understanding of how date filtering is used in creating values for each period in a report.  With the day-based approach having a finer resolution, can you help me understand why we wouldn't simply used the day-based approach in all cases? Is it because using the day based approach for periods greater than a month wouldn't correctly account for the varying number of days in a calendar month, while the month-based approach does?

Comment: That is correct - the DAY approach would give only the last 28(29) days in Jan from Feb. The DAY approach is mainly there in case you needed Weekly granularity. If you're happy with the answer above, then please accept it for the benefit of all.

Comment: This is really good stuff, I'll use this pattern often! I'm somewhat surprised I haven't come across this approach in tutorials, etc, given how broadly applicable it is