# Customer retention using DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to calculate customer retention over the years and, I want to find New customers, returning customers, and lost customers and lead to the retention rate.

I tried many methods using DAX, but seems like I am not being able to conclude an answer

Comment: What methods have you tried? These types of questions are too vague and we cannot help. Provide more detail and have a specific ask/question. In the meantime, see if this inspires you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77398759